# Обращения к свойствам файла из класса. ASP.Net

Tags: c#, ооп, asp.net, маршрутизация, делегаты

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, решить **2** вопроса.

1) Есть страница сайта, на которой располагается `asp:Label`. На северной части происходит обращение к классу, в котором выполняется обработка. Как из данного класса обратиться к свойству `Text` - `Label'а`?

2) Есть **master-страница**, на которой так же располагается `asp:Label`. Как изменить свойство `Text` данного лейбела с серверной части дочерний страницы?

Предположение: Использовать объектно-ориентированный подход и делать через `get, set`. Вот только может быть и такое, что оба вопроса нужно учесть, что приводит к необходимости обратиться из класса (на который я выхожу из дочерний страницы) к свойству `Label'а`, который находиться на `master-странице`. Как начинающего в данной области, меня это пугает. К тому же, надеюсь что есть и другие способы взаимодействия.

**UPD:**

Пытаюсь из дочерний страницы сделать обращение к элементу на master-page.

Элемент:

```
<asp:Label ID="Access_error" runat="server" Text="test53"></asp:Label>
```

Обращение:

```
Label lbl_TitlePage = Page.Master.FindControl("Access_error") as Label;
lbl_TitlePage.Text = "THE KEY QUESTIONS";
```

Проверяю через отладчик и вижу, что `lbl_TitlePage = null`.

Хотя, если смотреть свойства Master во время отладки, то он прекрасно видит `Label`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `FindControl` - ищет только контролы, непосредственно принадлежащие данному родителю. Вам надо это делать рекурсивно.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, что не оставляет меня один на один с бедой. Не соображу, как реализовать рекурсию в данном случае( Да и с прошлым не понял. Почему взят именно delegat. Почему не get,set (при том, даже get не нужно использовать)? Реализация с delegatom выглядит сомнительно. Хотелось бы, конечно, конкретный пример увидеть. Ну или пояснения строк делегата. Знаю, что многого прошу. В такие дебри я ещё не забирался. Хорошо бы было хоть немного разобраться, чтобы быть в теме

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заведите в Вашем классе свойство-делегат, которое класс будет использовать, когда ему нужно обратиться к `Label.Text`, не зная, что происходит внутри вызванного делегата. Дочерняя страница, которая создает объект класс, пусть назначает (добавляет) свой метод к этому делегату, а в методе уже обращается к своему или родительскому `Label`у.

```
  public delegate void SendString(string aValue);

  public class BusinessLogic
  {
    public SendString SendStringEvent;

    public void Execute()
    {
      string textToSend = "test";
      if (SendStringEvent != null)
        SendStringEvent(textToSend );
    }
  }


  class Program
  {
    static void SendStringEventHandler(string a)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("*** {0} ***", a));
    }

    static void Main()
    {
      BusinessLogic logic = new BusinessLogic();
      logic.SendStringEvent += SendStringEventHandler;
      logic.Execute();
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
```

*Update*

```
public static class ControlFinder
{
  public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control aParent, string anId)
  {
    Control result = aParent.FindControl(anId);
    if (result != null)
      return result;

    foreach (Control child in aParent.Controls)
    {
      result = child.FindControlRecursive(anId);
      if (result != null)
        return result;
    }

    return null;
  }
}

Label lbl_TitlePage = Page.Master.FindControlRecursive("Access_error") as Label;
```

Comment: А можете привести простой пример, пожалуйста. С таким я ещё не сталкивался.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! У меня, правда, отладчик ругался на `FindControlRecursive` и на `return`. А так, я нашёл ответ на второй вопрос сам.

Comment: @Egor пардон, я пропустил тип возвращаемого значения в декларации `FindControlRecursive`. Добавил.

Comment: С return действительно решились проблемы. Но на `FindControlRecursive` отладчик продолжает ругаться =( https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7K9W.png

Comment: @Egor передвиньте класс `ControlFinder`, чтобы он находился непосредственно в `namespace`

Comment: гениально, спасибо. Это работает). Теперь буду разбираться с делегатом. А так, можете оценить, лучше использовать ваше предложение по решению второго вопроса или моё?

Comment: @Egor Ваше. Я сторонник получения ошибок во время компиляции - когда проблемы с кодом автоматически находит компилятор, а не во время выполнения, когда то, что контрол не найден (из-за опечатки в литерал строке или переименования), выяснится слишком поздно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и честность. Во всяком случае Вы решили проблему и я давно хотел понять работу рекурса наглядно. + Описали пример делегата. В общем, это то, что мне очень нужно!

Comment: Возникла ещё проблема, для которой рекурсивный поиск оказался кстати - [вот новая тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684935/Поиск-контрола-и-его-изменение-asp-net). Однако возникла проблема с тем, что элемент с одним id используется несколько раз. Как можно перебрать все элементы с одним id, может Вы подскажете?

Answer (score 1):

Решение вопроса 2.

1) На стороне master-страницы:

```
<asp:Label ID="Access_error" runat="server" Text="test53"></asp:Label>
```

**C#**

```
public string AccessError
{
    set { Access_error.Text = value; }
    get { return Access_error.Text; }
}
```

2) На стороне дочерний страницы (страницы с содержанием):

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Явная ссылка на master-страницу" %>
```

**С#**

```
this.Master.AccessError = "Текст.";
```