# Поиск контрола и его изменение. Asp.Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, list, объекты, asp.net-webforms

Столкнулся с довольна серьёзной проблемой.

Использую `ListView`:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder"
ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder"> 
       <LayoutTemplate>
           <table border="1">
              <tr>
                   <th rowspan="3">Текст1</th>
                   <th rowspan="3">Текст2</th>
                   <th id="th_id1" runat="server" colspan="3">Текст4</th>
                   ...
              </tr>
              ...
              <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
              ...
           </table>
       </LayoutTemplate>
       <GroupTemplate>
           <tr>
               <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
           </tr>
       </GroupTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <td style="padding:10px">
               <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" CssClass="padding-table" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td style="padding:10px">
               <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" CssClass="padding-table" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td id="th_id9" runat="server" style="padding:10px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" CssClass="padding-table" Text='<%# Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Label>
           </td>
           ...
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Необходимо менять свойства `th_id1` и `th_id9`.

Получить доступ к `th_id1` не составляет труда:

```
var table = (HtmlTableCell)ListView1.FindControl("th_id1") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell;
```

А вот изменить `th_id9` не выходит, так как он не только не является частью таблицы, но и является расширяемым (отвечает за содержимое таблицы).

Ясно дело, что `th_id9` повторяется в большой таблице, поэтому каждой ячейки столбца дополнительно присваивается идентификатор `cntr`, который растёт от **0** и до последней ячейки в таблице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следовательно, пробую обращаться и на `th_id9` и на `cntr0`:

```
var table = (HtmlTableCell)ListView1.FindControl("th_id9") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell;
//var table2 = (HtmlTableCell)ListView1.FindControl("ctrl0") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell;
var table3 = (TableCell)ListView1.FindControl("th_id9") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell;
//var table14 = (TableCell)ListView1.FindControl("ctrl0") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell;
var table5 = (TableRow)ListView1.FindControl("th_id9") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow;
//var table6 = (TableRow)ListView1.FindControl("ctrl0") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow;
var table17 = (HtmlTableCell)ListView1.FindControl("ctrl0_th_id9") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell;
```

При использовании закомментированных строк получаю ошибку приведения типов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал и через `ListViewContainer`

```
var table10 = (ListViewContainer)ListView1.FindControl("ctrl0") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.ListViewContainer;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> **"ListViewContainer"** недоступен из-за его уровня защиты.

Как всё таки получить доступ к данным элементам?

**UPDATE:**

[Рекурсивный поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683084/248502) удачно справляется с данной задачей, но работает только на первой ячейке. Если делать в цикле, он становиться бесконечным

**UPDATE v2.0:**

Можно сделать переприсовение `ID`:

```
table9 = (HtmlTableCell)ListView1.FindControlRecursive("th_id9") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell;
while(table9 != null)
{
     table9.Visible = false;
     table9.ID = "th_id11";
     table9 = (HtmlTableCell)ListView1.FindControlRecursive("th_id9") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо сначала выбрать конкретную строку, а потом уже внутри нее искать нужный вам элемент:

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items) {
    var table9 = (HtmlTableCell)item.FindControlRecursive("th_id9") as HtmlTableCell;
}
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо)

Comment: А так, что конкретно ломается в моём случае? Я же просто даю контролам новый ID

Comment: @Egor любой код, который работает с контролом по ID.

Comment: Т.е. код, который будет работать с этим же контролом в будущем. А если такого нет, то, выходит, что использовать можно (да, глупо и не профессионально, но ведь можно).

Answer (score 0):

Я смутно помню, что доступ к контролам внутри `ItemTemplate` возможен только из событий заполнения/генерации записей в `ListView`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitemeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Спасибо=), но я нашёл простой ход. Сделать переприсвоение `table9.ID = "th_id11"`;

Comment: @Egor этим переприсвоением вы поломали много еще ненаписанного кода...